# is there a way to make a background scroll down while some content stay in the middle at all time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'm trying to do something like (in js, html, sass) :

- when I scroll the page down my layers (ground, sky, space, ...) go down
- my content (that will be a rocket going in the sky) stay in the middle of the screen and will move     to the sides like if it were to be flying (that will be for later)
- some elements will move on the layers (like asteroids going from right to left or something) (for later)

So here are some ideas of code I tried but this seem odd and do not work as intended; as you can see, the layers are scrolling as intended, but they are not all showing for whatever reason, they seem to fill all the page size but they shouldn't and i'm going round and round about this on the internet and no one seem to have done something like this.

```js
// Functions
detectPageVerticalPosition = () => {
  pageVerticalPosition = pageYOffset;
};

getDivs = () => {
  for (
    let div = document.getElementsByTagName("div"), i = 0; i < div.length; i++
  ) {
    div[i].getAttribute("class") == "layer-vertical" &&
      layerVerticalArray.push(div[i]);
  }
  console.log("layerVerticalArray: ", layerVerticalArray);
};

moveLayers = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < layerVerticalArray.length; i++) {
    layerVerticalArray[i].style.bottom = -1 * pageVerticalPosition + "px";
  }
};

// End Functions

// Variables
var pageVerticalPosition = 0,
  layerVerticalArray = new Array();
// End Variables

// Events
window.onload = e => {
  getDivs();
  // console.log(layerVerticalArray);
};

window.onscroll = e => {
  detectPageVerticalPosition();
  moveLayers();
};
// End Events
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#page {
  position: relative;
  height: 20000px;
  width: 100%;
}

#rocket-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#rocket-container #rocket {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
}

#background-container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#background-container .layer-vertical {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3500px;
}

#background-container #layer-vertical-1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
}

#background-container #layer-vertical-1 #cloud-1 {
  outline-style: dashed;
  right: 0px;
}

#background-container #layer-vertical-1 #cloud-2 {
  outline-style: dotted;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#background-container #layer-vertical-2 {
  background-color: green;
}

#background-container #layer-vertical-3 {
  background-color: purple;
}

.cloud {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 120px;
  background-image: url(../images/cloud.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="background-container">
    <div class="layer-vertical" id="layer-vertical-1">
      Layer 1
      <div class="cloud" id="cloud-1"></div>
      <div class="cloud" id="cloud-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="layer-vertical" id="layer-vertical-2">
      Layer 2
    </div>
    <div class="layer-vertical" id="layer-vertical-3">
      Layer 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rocket-container">
    <div id="rocket">STAY MIDDLE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[1]: https://via.placeholder.com/180/120

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please change the images for something from lorempixel or placeholder.com into a [mcve]

Comment: Thx i already tought of using the parallax effect for the elements composing my layers
ps: i added a placeholder and thx for the snippets ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's what i found in order to fix this (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kjrte2sd/2/)

i used some jquery to make the background-container scroll down as intended instead of each elements scrolling down by himself.
now the page div is gone and the body handle the sizing of the whole thing.

i guess the answer was simpler than i expected it to be.

```js
var winHeight = $(window).innerHeight();

$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".layer-vertical").height(winHeight);
  $("body").height(winHeight * $(".layer-vertical").length);
});

window.addEventListener("resize", e => {
  $(".layer-vertical").height($(window).innerHeight());
});

$(window).on("scroll", () => {
  $("#background-container").css("bottom", $(window).scrollTop() * -1);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#rocket-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#rocket-container #rocket {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
}

#background-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#background-container .layer-vertical {
  width: 100%;
}

#background-container .layer-vertical h1 {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
}

#background-container #layer-vertical-1 {
  background-color: green;
}

#background-container #layer-vertical-2 {
  background-color: red;
}

#background-container #layer-vertical-3 {
  background-color: white;
}

#background-container #layer-vertical-4 {
  background-color: pink;
}

#background-container #layer-vertical-5 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background-container">
  <div class="layer-vertical" id="layer-vertical-5">
    <h1>5</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="layer-vertical" id="layer-vertical-4">
    <h1>4</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="layer-vertical" id="layer-vertical-3">
    <h1>3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="layer-vertical" id="layer-vertical-2">
    <h1>2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="layer-vertical" id="layer-vertical-1">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="rocket-container">
  <div id="rocket">STAY MIDDLE</div>
</div>
```